# Objective-C : Create child data for a selected parent core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, parent-child, entity-relationship

-I have 2 entities and 2 views **BookStore** and **Book**.

- 1 **BookStore** can have many **Book** (one-to-many)

-The first view is **BookStore** tableView and when i click in a **BookStore**(indexPath) it will open the second view which is to add **Book** for that **BookStore**(indexPath).

-The problem that I cant find a way to make **Book** a child of **BookStore** .That create a **Book** for that selected **BookStore**

[My coredata entities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ER0jF.png)

Comment: Why is there one-to-many from book to bookstore? It should be in reverse direction.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should change your relashionships, so that BookStore has many books instead of book having multiple stores
   [image]
2. Your dataSource in BookStoreViewController should store an array of books, right? You just have to pick the right one in `didSelectRowAtIndexpath` method using the indexPath and pass it to a new BookViewController.